# Saving user preferences in Java

Tags: java

I am needing to get some user information, save it and reload them once the app is reopened. How do I save the user data and reload them once the app opens? Sorry I am new to Java and not sure where to get started

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html

Maybe the prefs API can provide what you are looking for?

This package allows applications to store and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data.